# capitalizes sentence correctly in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, conditional-statements

I want to write a program which takes a string as input and print a new copy of the string that has been correctly capitalized. My function should:

● Capitalize the first letter in the string 
● Capitalize the first letter after a full-stop, exclamation mark or question mark 
● Capitalize the word “i” if it is in lowercase.

**Sample Input:**  my favourite animal is a dog. a dog has sharp teeth so that it can eat flesh very easily. do you know my pet dog’s name? i love my pet very much.

**Sample Output:**  My favourite animal is a dog. A dog has sharp teeth so that it can eat flesh very easily. Do you know my pet dog’s name? I love my pet very much.

My code:

```
s = ('my favourite animal is a dog. a dog has sharp teeth so that it can eat flesh very easily. do you know my pet dog’s name? i love my pet very much.')

output = ''
count = 0
fl = 0
for i in s:
    if count == 0:
        output += i.upper()
        count += 1
    elif i == ' ':
        output += i
    elif i == '.' or '!' or '?':
        output += i
        fl = 1
    elif fl == 1:
        output += i.upper()
        fl = 0
    else:
        output += i

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third `elif` condition has a mistake,

You have done :

```
elif i == '.' or '!' or '?':
```

This means that `'!' or '?'` is being computed everytime, which always results to `True` and never reaches the next required `elif fl == 1:` condition which handles the `upper()` logic.

The correct `elif` condition would be :

```
elif i == '.' or i == '!' or i == '?':
```

(Edit) for a single 'i' in the string, you'll need to implement a lookahead, I have changed the code below.

The corrected code :

```
s = ('my favourite animal is a dog. a dog has sharp teeth so that it can eat flesh very easily. do you know my pet dog’s name? i love my pet i very much. i')

output = ''
count = 0
fl = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if count == 0:
        output += s[i].upper()
        count += 1
    elif s[i] == 'i':
        # handle end of string for the lookahead below
        if i == len(s)-1:
            output += s[i].upper()
        elif s[i+1] == ' ':
            output += s[i].upper()
    elif s[i] == ' ':
        output += s[i]
    elif s[i] == '.' or s[i] == '!' or s[i] == '?':
        output += s[i]
        fl = 1
    elif fl == 1:
        output += s[i].upper()
        fl = 0
    else:
        output += s[i]

print(output)
```

Comment: if the string has a word 'I', it will not work properly.

Comment: @Shakiib edit the answer. It would require some lookahead, so the answer becomes a bit more complicated, I have also changed the sample string `s`